# Graph homomorphism, and how to proof?

Tags: graph-theory

1. I want to know whether there exists a homomorphism from this graph (below in the image) to $K_5$ (complete graph with 5 vertices).
2. If so, how can I prove this relationship? Since homomorphism is a new concept to me, I can not easily find a function mapping according to the definition of homomorphism.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to know whether there exists a homomorphism $G \to K_5$ or the other way around?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "homomorphism to $K_5$", do you mean the isomorphism? Or there's a homomorphism from this graph to $K_5$?

Comment: yes, I want to know whether there exists a homomorphism G -> K5.@user133281

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Apologize since I've mistook this graph as a planar graph. But this graph admits a four-coloring:
 [image]

Comment: actually, I want to use homomorphism to prove that this graph is a planar graph. That is why I want to know this graph is homomorphism  to K5.

Comment: Is $K_5$ a planar graph?

Comment: no K5 is not a planar graph@Tunococ

Comment: So your proof of homomorphism here is by transfer the problem into a 4-coloring problem. Thus there exists a 4 corloring label for the graph above is sufficient to claim, the graph above has a homomorphism relation with K4? Can I do the same statement for K5?

Comment: @user2262504 Since $K_4$ is a subgraph of $K_5$, so there's a homomorphism between $G$ and $K_5$...

Comment: Thanks, Can you give some materials on the proof of homomorphism and k-coloring. I am really quite new to this concept.

Comment: Maybe you can read "Graphs and Homomorphisms" see here:http://www.amazon.com/Graphs-Homomorphisms-Lecture-Mathematics-Applications/dp/0198528175 . I'm not sure if it may help. If the book is unavailable in library, I recommended bookzz.org for electronic version.